# Loading data from file into MySQL table with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I need to load data from a file into a table with a foreign key constraint. If I have the parent table populated and want to populate the child how do I find the appropriate foreign key for the child. I.E. if I have a department and employee table where employee contains fk_department_id but no other identifying information about department, how do I know what department the employee belongs to. I was thinking of using temporary tables that contained identifying information about the department (like the department name) in the employee table and using join to get the appropriate fk's. Then put that info without the extra identifying columns into the database, but I don't think that would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First load data for the department table, and after execute the following using department name in employee csv, ex.:

```
Department csv: DeptName, Manager ("Finance","Ted Smith")

Department table: de_id, de_name, de_manager

Emplstrong textoyee csv: Name, Surname, DeptName ("Tom", "Smith", "Finance")

Employee table: em_id, em_name, em_surname, em_de_id

LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Temp\\Employee.csv' INTO TABLE `tbl_employees` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 

(em_name, em_surname,  @ColVar3) 
SET `em_de_id` = (SELECT de_id FROM tbl_departments WHERE de_name = @ColVar3)
```

I have used it in mySQL 5.1